# ASP.net Application_Start catch exception in timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, exception

Given the following code in `Global.asax`, the first exception thrown is correctly caught but the timer exception is not.

What do I need to change to catch any exceptions in the timer?

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // THIS WORKS
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Test!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Code.Helpers.Error.Functions.RecordError(ex);
    }

    // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    try
    {
        var myTimer = new Timer(
            Code.Helpers.MyTimer.Process,
            null,
            new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0),
            Settings.ProcessMyTimerEvery);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Code.Helpers.Error.Functions.RecordError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which exception do you expect in second `try`? You only create `Timer` instance.

Comment: You need to put `try/catch` inside timer event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the `try` / `catch` block inside the timer callback (`Code.Helpers.MyTimer.Process` in your case).

Answer (score 3):

From the [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) docs (emphasis mine):

> Provides a mechanism for executing a method **on a thread pool** thread at specified intervals.

It's also worth reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah1h85ch(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The method specified for *callback* should be reentrant, because it is called on ThreadPool threads. The method can be executed simultaneously on two thread pool threads if the timer interval is less than the time required to execute the method, or if all thread pool threads are in use and the method is queued multiple times.

This means the delegate you pass into the timer is not called on the same thread where your timer exists. To catch exceptions in your timer event, you need to put the try/catch in there. For example:

```
var myTimer = new Timer(
    TimerEvent, //<-- A delegate to the TimerEvent method
    null, 
    new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0), 
    new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5));
```

And your timer code:

```
private void TimerEvent(object x)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception in timer event");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Code.Helpers.Error.Functions.RecordError(ex);
    }
}
```